# How to programmatically change SurfaceView orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

We need our android app to support Android V2.3 through to V5. We are rendering a Surface view inside a LinearLayout. Our Activity is locked to portrait.

We would like to programmatically rotate the SurfaceView with the same effect as though it changed from Portrait to Landscape. The SurfaceView is dynamically created in code and added to the LinearLayout which is defined in the xml. We wish to keep other views the same, this is why we need to fix the Activity orientation. How do we go about this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Wherever you use sthe camera, set the orientation to 90 degrees:

```
  mCamera = Camera.open();
  mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Comment: SurfaceView is not rotating

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157984/android-camera-surfaceview-orientation or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455399/rotating-a-camera-surfaceview-to-portrait

Comment: Hi, It is not the camera surface view I have the problem rotating. It is rendered Surface view of video from remote end

Comment: RotateAnimation rotate= new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                                    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
                                    remoteSurface.setAnimation(rotate);

Comment: Have you tried adding the rotation attr on the surface view in your layout xml?

Comment: I create the SurfaceView dynamically and add it to a LinearLayout

Comment: Does this work: surfaceViewObject.setrotation(90); ?

Comment: Video stops playing when I do that, just black view now

Comment: although it appears it rotated